# Horizontal smooth scroll to next/previous anchor-id with mouse wheel using url

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, mousewheel

First question here, hoping someone could help me or point me in the right direction.

I developing a website which scrolls horizontally using scrollTo and localscroll. Here is a jsfiddle showing the setup: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Katalo/m4d2b9nd/2/)
I wonder if there is a way to use the mouse wheel to scroll smoothly to the next anchor horizontally and changing the url so it displays the current anchor. Basicly if the mouse wheel can simulate a click on prev/next ?

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'xy';
    $.localScroll({
        target: '#content', 
        queue:true,
        duration:1500,
        hash:true
    });
});
```